# xorm How to convert a QueryInterface map[string]interface{} back to the xorm defined struct?

Tags: go, go-xorm

I have a database query that returns an extra calculated column along with all the mapped struct columns. I want to map it back into the struct while also being able to extract the calculated column which is not part of the struct. I can get everything by using the xorm `QueryInterface()` function, but I can't seem to find how I can convert the resulting `map[string]interface{}` back into the struct...

Any idea? I saw gorm has `db.Model(...).Create(...)` but can't seem to find the equivalent in xorm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution, though not an elegant one, I wish there was something better, so if someone else has a good answer...

I basically just decided to use JSON Marshal then Unmarshal to take the `map[string]interface{}` and turn it back into the struct. This means I had to use a bunch of `json:"..."` tags on the struct, as the column->property mapping differed from those used by xorm. Kinda ugly but it allowed me to capture the extra props from the database query.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ID                   int64              `xorm:"primaryKey"`
    ProductID            int64              `xorm:"INDEX" json:"product_id"`
    Index                int64              `xorm:"INDEX NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"`
    Code                 string             `xorm:"-" json:"code"`
}

func (b *MyDBStruct) FromMap(src map[string]interface{}) error {
    jsonStr, _ := json.Marshal(src)
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &b)
    if err == nil {
        for key := range src {
            b.AfterSet(key, nil)
        }
    }
    return err
}
```